# Security issues. PHP window.location

Tags: php, ajax, security, header

i have created this application which creates a csv file from given list from DB and than allows user to download it! When i finished the job i came to realise that there is a security issues!

Here is the ajas i am using to make a request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:HTTPS + '/lib/model/data/ctlRates.php?export=1',
            data: {
                ext: ext,
                filter: filter,
                fileName: fileName
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data['results'] == "success"){
                    console.log(data['results']);
                    var filename = data['filename'];
                    var extension = data['ext'];
                    window.location = HTTPS + '/lib/model/data/ctlRates.php download=1&filename='+filename+'&ext='+extension;
                } else {
                    console.log(data['results']);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error: File name and extension must be provided");
    }
});
```

And i imagine that most of you already sees the problem!
but here is the controller to which window.location is pointing:

```
if(isset($_GET['download']) && $_GET['download'] == 1){
$filePath = "/path/to/file/dir";
$name = $_GET['filename'];
$extension = $_GET['ext'];

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: text/'.$extension.'');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.".".$extension.'');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: public");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filePath.$name.".".$extension);

}
```

Started testing and came to realize that everyone can ender filename and extension they pleases and get files from that directory....Any ideas how to burry this hole?

Comment: Something like password-protect your app or validate user input?

Comment: How you implement that would be dependent on what you would like to accomplish with your application. So, some pointers in that direction might help.

Comment: What i am trying to acomplish is to let user download a csv/xls/txt file genereated from list (which user chooses himself entering in filter what he wants to see).

Answer (score 0):

> And i imagine that most of you already sees the problem!

Not really - there are very few security issues i javascript - and this does not exhibit any of them - the problem is how you are procesing your data server-side. Do not attempt to server security holes with javascript changes.

If you want to restrict access to a specific directory tree...

```
if(isset($_GET['download']) && $_GET['download'] == 1){
    $filePath = "/path/to/file/dir";
    $fetchfrom = realpath($filepath . '/' 
        . /* basename( */ $name /* ) */ 
        . "." . $extension);
    if (substr($fetchfrom, 0, strlen($filepath))!=$filepath) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
         print "Directory traversal not allowed";
         exit;
    }
```